# MySql workbench font size

Tags: fonts, interface, size, mysql-workbench

http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=g5tu1o5nmt2a.png

All the text in the picture is very small...
How can I make it bigger? it really hurts my eyes

Answer (score 1):

Set a bigger scaling factor on your Windows box.

Comment: Thx man, is it the only way to make it bigger? because it affects my whole computer.

Comment: I understand your pain, but most of the UI is made of standard UI controls and they show in the default size the OS dictates. This is why the system scaling exists at all. It's not well solved in Windows and we are still thinking how to make this working cleanly (it's not only fontsize change, but all elements must be adjusted, e.g. tabs, list line heights etc.).